# Windows 7 and bind DNS for private use not resolving

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, dns, bind

I am a web developer and I run a personal DNS server (linux, bind) within Virtualbox on IP 192.168.0.3 to test web sites.

I have configured a test domain `www.olympias.dom` within bind and I have configured a virtual host in Apache for the same.

When I test the DNS configuration for `www.olympias.dom` using nslookup on the host machine (Windows 7), I get the expected result:

> C:\Users\user>nslookup www.olympias.dom
>   Server:  UnKnown
>   Address:  192.168.0.3
>
> Name:    olympias.dom
>   Address:  192.168.0.3
>   Aliases:  www.olympias.dom

However, **I cannot reach the address in my browser** (Chrome) and when I ping it I receive the following error:

> C:\Users\user>ping www.olympias.dom
>   Ping request could not find host www.olympias.dom. Please check the name and try
>   again.

Everything works as expected if I configure the domain using the Windows hosts file **but I want it to work via the DNS server**. This setup (Vbox=DNS/Apache) worked properly when I used Windows XP but it is not working in Windows 7 Home Premium.

What is wrong? Any help?